# how to get around setting foreign key property explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have the following entity class:

```
public class Config{
  public Method Method{get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("Method")]
  public int Method_Id{get;set;}
}

...
//in controller when assigning Method:
config.Method = dbContext.Methods.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == methodId);
//without this statement, the update doesn't work!
config.Method_Id = config.Method.Id;

//when saving in dbcontext
dbSet.AddOrUpdate(config);
```

How can I get around also having to set foreign key id every time?

Comment: You already used `methodId` to search for it. Why not skip that and assign `methodId` to `config.Method_Id` instead?

Comment: You can skip this line "config.Method_Id = config.Method.Id;". When you say failing, what is the error?

Comment: there's no error, the update just doesn't happen.

Comment: @madreflection that's beside the point. I am just asking whether there's a way to update Method_Id when I update Method without having to explicitly update it.

Comment: Implement it in the `Method` property. Have it take `value.Id` and assign that to the `Method_Id` property.